# Stored procedure to remove FK of a given table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to create a stored procedure that:

1. Accepts a table name as a parameter
2. Find its dependencies (FKs)
3. Removes them
4. Truncate the table

I created the following so far based on http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1376/disable-enable-drop-and-recreate-sql-server-foreign-keys/ . My problem is that the following script successfully does 1 and 2 and generates queries to alter tables but does not actually execute them. In another word how  can execute the resulting "Alter Table ..." queries to actually remove FKs?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropDependencies(@TableName VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE referenced_object_id=object_id(@TableName)
END



EXEC DropDependencies 'TableName'
```

Any idea is appreciated!

Update:
I added the cursor to the SP but I still get and error: 
"Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure DropRestoreDependencies, Line 75
    The name 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChildTable]  DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__ChileTable__ParentTable__745C7C5D]' is not a valid identifier."

Here is the updated SP:
CREATE PROCEDURE DropRestoreDependencies(@schemaName sysname, @tableName sysname)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

```
DECLARE @operation VARCHAR(10)  


SET @operation = 'DROP' --ENABLE, DISABLE, DROP  


DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000) 

DECLARE   
   @FK_NAME sysname,  
   @FK_OBJECTID INT,  
   @FK_DISABLED INT,  
   @FK_NOT_FOR_REPLICATION INT,  
   @DELETE_RULE    smallint,     
   @UPDATE_RULE    smallint,     
   @FKTABLE_NAME sysname,  
   @FKTABLE_OWNER sysname,  
   @PKTABLE_NAME sysname,  
   @PKTABLE_OWNER sysname,  
   @FKCOLUMN_NAME sysname,  
   @PKCOLUMN_NAME sysname,  
   @CONSTRAINT_COLID INT  


DECLARE cursor_fkeys CURSOR FOR   
   SELECT  Fk.name,  
           Fk.OBJECT_ID,   
           Fk.is_disabled,   
           Fk.is_not_for_replication,   
           Fk.delete_referential_action,   
           Fk.update_referential_action,   
           OBJECT_NAME(Fk.parent_object_id) AS Fk_table_name,   
           schema_name(Fk.schema_id) AS Fk_table_schema,   
           TbR.name AS Pk_table_name,   
           schema_name(TbR.schema_id) Pk_table_schema  
   FROM    sys.foreign_keys Fk LEFT OUTER JOIN   
           sys.tables TbR ON TbR.OBJECT_ID = Fk.referenced_object_id --inner join   
   WHERE   TbR.name = @tableName  
           AND schema_name(TbR.schema_id) = @schemaName  

OPEN cursor_fkeys  

FETCH NEXT FROM   cursor_fkeys   
   INTO @FK_NAME,@FK_OBJECTID,  
       @FK_DISABLED,  
       @FK_NOT_FOR_REPLICATION,  
       @DELETE_RULE,     
       @UPDATE_RULE,     
       @FKTABLE_NAME,  
       @FKTABLE_OWNER,  
       @PKTABLE_NAME,  
       @PKTABLE_OWNER  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

   -- create statement for dropping FK and also for recreating FK  
   IF @operation = 'DROP'  
   BEGIN  

       -- drop statement  
       SET @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @FKTABLE_OWNER + '].[' + @FKTABLE_NAME   
       + ']  DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @FK_NAME + ']'     

      EXEC @cmd  

       -- create process  
       DECLARE @FKCOLUMNS VARCHAR(1000), @PKCOLUMNS VARCHAR(1000), @COUNTER INT  

       -- create cursor to get FK columns  
       DECLARE cursor_fkeyCols CURSOR FOR   
       SELECT  COL_NAME(Fk.parent_object_id, Fk_Cl.parent_column_id) AS Fk_col_name,   
               COL_NAME(Fk.referenced_object_id, Fk_Cl.referenced_column_id) AS Pk_col_name  
       FROM    sys.foreign_keys Fk LEFT OUTER JOIN   
               sys.tables TbR ON TbR.OBJECT_ID = Fk.referenced_object_id INNER JOIN   
               sys.foreign_key_columns Fk_Cl ON Fk_Cl.constraint_object_id = Fk.OBJECT_ID   
       WHERE   TbR.name = @tableName  
               AND schema_name(TbR.schema_id) = @schemaName  
               AND Fk_Cl.constraint_object_id = @FK_OBJECTID -- added 6/12/2008  
       ORDER BY Fk_Cl.constraint_column_id  

       OPEN cursor_fkeyCols  

       FETCH NEXT FROM    cursor_fkeyCols INTO @FKCOLUMN_NAME,@PKCOLUMN_NAME  

       SET @COUNTER = 1  
       SET @FKCOLUMNS = ''  
       SET @PKCOLUMNS = ''  

       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
       BEGIN   

           IF @COUNTER > 1   
           BEGIN  
               SET @FKCOLUMNS = @FKCOLUMNS + ','  
               SET @PKCOLUMNS = @PKCOLUMNS + ','  
           END  

           SET @FKCOLUMNS = @FKCOLUMNS + '[' + @FKCOLUMN_NAME + ']'  
           SET @PKCOLUMNS = @PKCOLUMNS + '[' + @PKCOLUMN_NAME + ']'  

           SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1  

           FETCH NEXT FROM    cursor_fkeyCols INTO @FKCOLUMN_NAME,@PKCOLUMN_NAME  
       END  

       CLOSE cursor_fkeyCols   
       DEALLOCATE cursor_fkeyCols   



   END  

   FETCH NEXT FROM    cursor_fkeys   
      INTO @FK_NAME,@FK_OBJECTID,  
           @FK_DISABLED,  
           @FK_NOT_FOR_REPLICATION,  
           @DELETE_RULE,     
           @UPDATE_RULE,     
           @FKTABLE_NAME,  
           @FKTABLE_OWNER,  
           @PKTABLE_NAME,  
           @PKTABLE_OWNER  
END  

CLOSE cursor_fkeys   
DEALLOCATE cursor_fkeys 
END
```

For running use:

```
EXEC DropRestoreDependencies dbo, ParentTable
```

Comment: Use a cursor to go through your SELECT results, populating a variable with the single column, and executing that query with EXEC(@YourVariable)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I use cursor but I still an error. I updated my question with the new stored procedure.

Comment: Put a "PRINT @cmd" statement on the line before the "EXEC @cmd" statement and look at what command it is attempting to execute when it triggers the error.

Comment: @Tab Alleman I did and ran the resulted queries separably. They work without any problems.

Comment: Oh, you need to use parens with EXEC.   So change it to "EXEC (@cmd)"

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! It  is working! If you want, add your comment as answer and and I will select it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cursor to go through your SELECT results, populating a variable with the single column, and executing that query with EXEC(@YourVariable).   Be sure to use parens around the variable!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are only preparing the SQL statement and not executing it (I think)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DropDependencies(@TableName VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE referenced_object_id=object_id(@TableName)
EXEC @SQL
END


EXEC DropDependencies 'TableName'
```

Whenever using EXEC though from constructed strings, ensure you aren't vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now The problem is only one result is assigned to the @SQL. In some cases I have more than one dependencies!

Comment: @nicole Ah, I follow. May need to set up a cursor and run through for each result. Cursors are evil, however, so there may be a better way

Comment: I already used the cursor but I get the error that "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT ...' is not a valid identifier."

Comment: @nicole you'll need to create the cursor in the sp created and execute the sql for each constraint found?

Comment: Yes! (It is not in the question as it is too long but I used the code in http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1376/disable-enable-drop-and-recreate-sql-server-foreign-keys/  and changed it to a stored procedure. when I change print to exec in the drop section, I get the error that I mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

Try Out [SP_ExecuteSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) or [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx). I see that you are using Exec. Perhaps `SP_ExecuteSQL` will work?